Raspberry Pi Remote Connection Error
I am trying to remotely connect to my raspberry pi zero w. I have found a common occurence that to do this you need to install xrdp. So I used the following commands:
sudo apt-get install xrdp
sudo apt-get install tightvncserver

I have used those commands and tried many others but when I try to remotely connect to it using the native Windows tool remote desktop connection. But when I put in the hostname, username, and password, I get the following error:

When I enter the information to connect to it remotely, it just shows a blue screen for a couple of minutes. I also tried to connect to it just by using putty and that worked, but I am hoping that I can access the Gui using remote desktop connection or some other software that does the same thing.

also i dont even know if you can even remotely use a raspberry pi zero w through remote desktop connection

Please [edit] and add any additional info to the question and not in the comments, thanks.

What I figured out is that remote desktop connection never worked. So I decided to use RealVnc instead by turning it on from my raspberry pi.
This video really helped:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWBmYnNvN3A
